# Change controller route name in ASP.NET Core MVC 404 error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I want to change the route display name in URL, like below:

Access `UserController` display: https://localhost:7214/admin/login

Access `CustomerController` display: https://localhost:7214/customers/index

**UserController.cs**

```
[Route("admin")]
public class UserController : Controller
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;

        return View();
    }
}
```

**CustomerController.cs**

```
[Route("customers")]
public class CustomerController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Admin}/{action=Login}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

But when I run the program, hit the following error:

[image]

I don't want to use [`Areas`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-6.0), any other options other than `Areas`?

**Updated:**

I modified code below in **Program.cs**

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "customers",
    pattern: "customers/{action}/{id?}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Customer", action = "Index" });
```

Access index page is find, but access route method, hit error 404.

```
public class CustomerController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()  <-- working fine
    {
        return View();
    }

    [Route("test/export")]
    public IActionResult Test()  <-- error 404
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Routing from Contoller using Route attribute,

UserController:

```
[Route("admin/[action]/{id?}")]
public class UserController : Controller
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;

        return View();
    }
}
```

CustomerController:

```
[Route("customers/[action]/{id?}")]
public class CustomerController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Or you can add route in Startup.cs (Program.cs file for 6.0 and up).

Multiple conventional routes:

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "demo",
                pattern: "admin/{action}/{id?}",
                defaults: new { controller = "User", action = "Login" });

app.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "demo2",
                pattern: "customers/{action}/{id?}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Customer", action = "Index" });
```

Reference: Asp.net core Docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: Hi, please refer my updated code, i have error 404 again if follow second method.

Comment: [Route("test")]  --> remove this

Comment: Thanks, but I found another issue on second approach, for the customer, I tried both URL `/customers/index` or `/customer/index` , realized that without `s` also able to access the page

Comment: For first approach, if I add `[Route("homes/{action}/{id?}")]` on start up page controller will hit 404 too,

Comment: " for the customer, I tried both URL /customers/index or /customer/index , realized that without s also able to access the page...."



/customer/index works because of 
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

Comment: if I want routing the default page too, how do I make it?

Comment: You should use the first approach. It is easy and perfect solution for your issues. If you want to use 2nd  approach, you have to add all controllers and  actions route one by one

Comment: I refer first approach, uploaded the code, https://github.com/howardhee/RoutingError  Just added [Route("homes/{action}/{id?}")] on Home controller then hit the error 404 while start the program.

Comment: HomeController is different. Home/Index can be match for https://localhost:7118/ OR https://localhost:7118/home or https://localhost:7118/home/index. So you need to add multiple route for HomeController. Please check this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#combining-attribute-routes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247475/discussion-between-tanzim-siddiqee-and-howard-hee).

Answer (score 0):

Since you have applied the attribute routing, the actions method should also be applied with attribute routing too.

**Solution 1**

> UserController.cs

```cs
[Route("admin")]
public class UserController : Controller
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet("login")]
    public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;

        return View();
    }
}
```

> CustomerController.cs

```cs
[Route("customers")]
public class CustomerController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("index")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

> Demo

[image]

---

**Solution 2**

Refer to the demo for defining the route for Controller (level) with [Attribute Routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/porting-existing-aspnet-apps/routing-differences#attribute-routing),

```cs
[Route("api/{controller}/{action}/{id?:int}")]
public abstract class BaseApiController : ControllerBase, IApiController
{
    // ...
}
```

> UserController.cs

```cs
[Route("admin/{action}/{id?}")]
public class UserController : Controller
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;

        return View();
    }
}
```

> CustomerController.cs

```cs
[Route("customers/{action}/{id?}")]
public class CustomerController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

> Demo

[image]

Comment: But it's not work on start up page, your default page is `Home`, if set the route on Home will hit error 404.

Comment: Please refer my updated code, even I tried use `[Route("customers/{action}/{id?}")]` , still have error during access `test` method

Comment: I see, how about the issue `[Route("homes/{action}/{id?}")]` ? I try set this on default start up page, hit the 404, should I do any changes on Program.cs?

Comment: Do you mind sharing your repository for reproducing the error you mentioned?

Comment: I uploaded the code, https://github.com/howardhee/RoutingError.git   Just added `[Route("homes/{action}/{id?}")]` on Home controller then hit the error.